# PC won't boot up. Requires manual fsck

Tags: boot

I cannot boot my PC. I have searched Ask Ubuntu for this and found posts dated from 2015 and 2016 and I have followed the instructions. Going to Grub menu always brings me back to this screen:

[image]

```
/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
This root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

(initranfs)_

I am not by any measure "tech" minded so the community help as I understand it has not worked.

To raise some issues people have mentioned in the posts:

1. I don't double boot. I only have Ubuntu. Windows has been uninstalled and replaced by Ubuntu.
2. I cannot run fsck - all posts I have consulted do not give me a starting point what to do to get to the needed starting point or anything I can readilly identify in order to do the steps suggested, i.e., I am totally lost - don't know from where to begin.  I assume one needs to have some programming knowledge to understand what is being suggested.
3. Entering "help" in BusyBox just brings up commands in alphabetical order but I have no idea what to do from there.

Comment: The easiest way is to boot 'live' media (eg. Ubuntu install media and selecting "Try Ubuntu") then `fsck` your partition(s) from there. By booting the 'live' media your hdd/ssd won't be in use, so you won't have any in-use issues blocking you. You can use commands, or if you boot a desktop media, can do the `fsck` using `gnome-disks`, `gparted` or another GUI tool using point & click.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do this out of initramfs:

```
fsck.ext3 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: I have tried the command line suggested.  I het the following message :(initramfs) fsck.ext3 /dev/sda11    sh: fsck.ext3/dev/sda1: not found           - I have also tried this command line with a space added after "ext3" but got the same result.         What do I do now ?  I still cannot boot my PC.

Comment: Well you can check which devices you have with ls `/dev/sda*` , based on your original post it should be sda1 , also the command might be either 'fsck.ext3' or 'fsck.ext4' , is it too hard to gain a live linux on stick ? That would be much easier zhan fiddling with your initramfs that we don't know. (And did you read yur sms inbox?)